# How is a dynamically-typed language implemented on top of a statically-typed language?

Tags: dynamic, static

I've only recently come to really grasp the difference between static and dynamic typing, by starting off with C++, and moving into Python and JavaScript. What I don't understand is how a dynamically-typed language (e.g. Python) can be implemented on top of a statically-typed language (e.g. C). I seem to remember reading something about void pointers once, but I didn't really get it.

Comment: Are you interested in C++ or any statically-typed language? There are some implementations on .NET for C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every variable in the d-t language is represented as a struct { type, value }, where a value is union/another struct/pointer etc.

In C++ you can get similar ("similar") result if you, for example, create a base abstract class MyVariable and derived MyInt, MyString etc. You can, with some more work, use these vars like in dynamically typed language. (I don't know C++ very well, but I think you'll need to use friend operators functions to change a type of variables in runtime, or maybe not, whatever)

This result is archieved by the same thing, runtime type information, which strores info of actual type in the object

I won't recommend it, though :)

Answer (score 3):

Basically, each "variable" of your dynamically typed language is represented by a structure in the statically typed language, which the data type being one of the fields. The operations on these dynamic data types (add, subtract, compare) are usually implemented by a [virtual method table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table), which is for each data type a number of pointers to functions that implement the desired functionality in a type-specific way.

Answer (score 1):

It's not. The dynamically typed language is implemented on top of a CPU architecture. As long as the CPU architecture is Turing complete, you can implement a static language on it, or a dynamic language, or something hybrid like the CLR/DLR of .NET. The important thing is that the Turing completeness of the CPU architecture is what enables or disables things, not the static nature of a programming language like C or C++.

In general, programming languages maintain Turing completeness, and therefore you can implement anything in any programming language. Of course some things are easier if the underlying tools support it, so it is not easy to implement an application that relies on a dynamic underpinning, in C or C++. That's why people put the effort into making a dynamic system that is programmable, like Python, so that you can implement the dynamic system once and suffer going through that extra effort only one time, then reuse it from the dynamic language layer.

Comment: Turing completeness does NOT mean "can implement anything". you can't implement AI, for example

Comment: Turing completeness is not a magic. For everything you trying to implement, you need to think about how you are going to do it.